# Forward ports to different subnetworks

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding, dvr

My network schema it´s the following;

I have a client with many branch offices, each one with its own subnet

For example:

- Headquarters network: 192.168.10.0 /24
- Branch office 01: 192.168.20.0 /24
- Branch office 02: 192.168.21.0 /24
- Branch office 03: 192.168.22.0 /24
- etc..

The connection between the offices it´s made by a MPLS connection provided by the ISP; which ends at each office in a Cisco 800 router (to which I have no access). I just put on the branch computers the Cisco 800 router IP as gateway and it works as a gem.

In parallel they have at the headquarters a Cisco RV042 router (to which I have admin access) to provide internet access to the headquarter office and branch offices

They are now installing DVR devices and they need to access them from outside the company. To do that I need to forward the ports on the RV042 router to the DVR located on the branch offices subnetworks; but when I try to do this the router tells me that the port forward can only be done to an IP on the same network.

> For example I try on the RV042 router (192.168.10.254) to configurate
>   a port forward to a DVR on branch office 01 (192.168.20.249)

I don´t know how to work around this, or if I´ll need another router which can perform this action.

Comment: Is port forwarding on always online 192.168.10.x LAN machine acceptable? Is your RV042 DMZ port free? Have you tried RV042 static routing and is its results same as port forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

From `RV042` manual:

> Enabling multiple subnets (IPv4 only)
>
> Typically, a Cisco RV0xx Series router is used as an access router, with a single LAN subnet. By default, the firewall is pre-configured to deny LAN access if the source IP address is on a different subnet than the router’s LAN IP address. However, you can enable multiple subnets to allow this router to work as an edge device that provides Internet connectivity to different subnets in your LAN.
>
> Step 1 > On the IPv4 tab, check the Enable Multiple Subnet box to enable this feature. Uncheck the box to disable this feature.
>
> Step 2 > Click Add/Edit to create or modify the subnets. After you click the button, the Multiple Subnet Management window appears.
>
> Step 3 > In the pop-up window, add or edit entries as needed.
>
> ...
>
> Step 4 > When you finish entering settings in the Multiple Subnet window, click OK to save
> your changes, or click Cancel to undo them.